# How to resolve or eliminate `AH01630: client denied by server configuration` error?

Tags: apache, error-logging

The server runs `Apache 2.4.25`, on Debian.

I recently tightened up security on a Wordpress site, to prevent PHP files from being executable in the `/wp-content/uploads/..` directories. This has been done with an `.htaccess` file, with the following content:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Since implementing this, I get a lot of the following entry in the Apache2 error log:

`[Fri Aug 17 06:48:10.027496 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 31416] [client 130.211.2.85:60354] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/index.php`

The IP addresses (of the many I have checked) all belong to Google. I assume their bots are for some reason trying to access `index.php` files in various `../uploads/..` folders. As there are no `index.php` files in those folders (and never have been) I am not sure why they would be doing that.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Under the given circumstances, is there a way to stop that error occurring? (e.g., To prevent Google bots from trying to access non-existent PHP files in the `uploads` directories)
2. If not, is there a way to configure Apache logging to not report that particular error? I'd rather not have to wade through them all whenever trying to find meaningful errors that are of concern to the well-being of the server.

**CONSIDERATIONS**

I realise I could set Apache `LogLevel` to `crit`, but I gather this will  eliminate all `error` (and below) logging. I don't wish to lose logging of other types of errors.

### HALF ANSWERED

I've posted an answer to Q2 below.

**Question 1** is still unanswered for me. One consideration is whether submitting an XML sitemap to Google (which will have no reference to index.php files in the `/uploads/` subdirectories), would prevent their bots from looking for such files.

One thing I've tried is adding `Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/*.php$` to the `robots.txt` file. After a few days, Google is still trying to access the files, and generating the error. (I reversed the Apache2 `LogLevel` changes whilst testing if the `robots.txt` changes would solve the problem). **So that was not a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

For **Question 2**, I have found the following resolves the issue. It is possible to set a the `LogLevel` in a way that is process specific. The reference to `[authz_core:error]` in the error message means it's the `authz_core` module generating the error I wish to remove. So I have modified `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, adding `authz_core:crit` to the line where `LogLevel` was set. That line now reads, `LogLevel warn authz_core:crit`.

So far, no more instances of the unwanted error have been logged.

Ideally, I think it would be a cleaner solution to prevent that error from being triggered at all. I am still open to suggestions on that. I've tried using the `robots.txt` file to prevent Google bots from accessing the files in question. It had no effect.